# Why is an array of lambdas created instead of an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, lambda

When I create an array like that, I get the output which I would expect:

```
val array1 = Array(26) { i -> ('a' + i).toString() }
println(array1.joinToString(" "))
```

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

But when I add additonal `{}` around the code it returns a lambda which is not expected:

```
val array2 = Array(26) { i-> { ('a' + i).toString() } }
println(array2.joinToString(" "))
```

Output:

> () -> kotlin.String () -> kotlin.String () -> kotlin.String () -> kotlin.String () -> kotlin.String...

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I really don't understand is why adding extra { } make it lambda, I used to use lambda in java and adding { } not changing anything

The basic lambda syntax in Java is `(<args>) -> { <body> }`, where `(` `)` can be omitted if `<args>` is a single identifier and `{` `}` can be omitted if `<body>` is a single expression.

In Kotlin it's `{ <args> -> <body> }`, where `{` `}` can't be omitted, but `<args> ->` or just `<args>` can, depending on number of arguments.

So adding `{` `}` in Kotlin is like adding `() -> {` `}` in Java (in this context).

Answer (score 3):

You are creating an array of lambdas in the second example, which are not invoked.

See that the inferred type is `Array<() -> String>`:

```
val array2: Array<() -> String> = Array(26) { i-> { ('a' + i).toString() } }
```

---

You can either invoke them by adding `()` at the end like that:

```
val array2 = Array(26) { i-> { ('a' + i).toString() }() }
```

Output will be again:

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

Or you just use the first example which is what you most likely want, because there is no reason to wrap that code into additional lambdas, if you just want to create an array of strings.

Comment: what I really don't understand is why adding extra { } make it lambda, I used to use lambda in java and adding { } not changing anything, I hope I get use to it in future

Comment: @IslamAssem In Kotlin you declare a lambda like that `{ /* ... */ }`. Array(26)({ i-> /* This is already a lambda*/ })

Comment: In Java, you can add braces pretty much anywhere to create a scope, but in Kotlin, this always creates a lambda. The alternative in Kotlin is to precede the braces with `run` to get a similar limited scope for the code within.

Comment: @IslamAssem Pls make an edit to your question and add the comment: "what I really don't understand is why adding extra { } make it lambda, I used to use lambda in java and adding { } not changing anything" to make it complete.

Comment: @IslamAssem it may also be a good idea to add the java tag then

Answer (score 2):

```
val array2 = Array(26) { i->{('a' + i).toString()}}
```

is an array of lambdas so each element is `() -> String`.

so in order to join it to a `String` you need to address it as lambda, for example:

```
 val str = array2.joinToString(" ") { it.invoke() }
 print(str)
//a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```